# Incorrect syntax near case in trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a `Reservations` table with the following columns

1. `Reservation_ID`
2. `Res_TotalAmount - money`
3. `Res_StartDate - datetime`
4. `IsDeleted  - bit` column with default value - false

So when a user tries to delete his reservation I've created a trigger that instead of delete - he just updates the value of column `IsDelete` to true;

So far so good - but this tourist may owe some compensation to the firm, for example when he has cancelled his reservation 30 days to 20 days from the `start_date` of the reservation - he owes 30% of the `Res_TotalAmount` and so on

And here is my trigger

```
Create Trigger tr_TotalAMountUpdateAfterInsert on RESERVATIONS after Delete 
As 
Begin
   Declare @period int
   Declare @oldResAmount int
   Declare @newAmount money
   Declare @resID int

   Select @resID = Reservation_ID from deleted 
   select @oldResAmount = Res_TotalAmount from deleted
   Select @period= datediff (day,Res_StartDate,GETDATE()) from deleted

   case 
      @period is between 30 and 20 then @newAmount=30%*@oldResAmount
      @period is between 20 and 10 then @newAmount=50%*@oldResAmount
   end

   exec sp_NewReservationTotalAmount @newAmount @resID
End 
GO
```

As I have to use both triggers and stored procedure you see that I call at the end of the trigger one stored procedure which just updates `Res_TotalAmount` column

```
Create proc sp_NewReservationTotalAmount(@newTotalAmount money, @resID)
As 
   declare @resID int 

   Update RESERVATIONS set Res_TotalAmount=@newTotalAmount where Reservation_ID=resID
```

GO

1. So my first problem is that it gives me incorrect syntax near case
2. And my second - I would appreciate suggestions how to make both the trigger and stored procedure better.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Here is the correct syntax for the CASE statement. Note that:

- I changed the order of your comparisons with the CASE statement; the smaller value has to come first.
- I have included an "ELSE" case so you don't wind up with an undefined value when @period is not within your given ranges

  ```
  SELECT @newAmount = 
   CASE  
    WHEN @period between 10 and 20 then 0.5 * @oldResAmount
    WHEN @period between 20 and 30 THEN 0.3 * @oldResAmount
    ELSE @oldResAmount
   END
  ```

2) You are going to have an issue with this trigger if ever a delete statement affects more than one row. Your statements like "SELECT @resID = Reservation_ID from deleted;" will simply assign one value from the deleted table at random.

---

EDIT

Here is an example of a set-based approach to your problem that will still work when multiple rows are "deleted" within the transaction (example code only; not tested):

```
Create Trigger tr_TotalAMountUpdateAfterInsert on RESERVATIONS after Delete 
As 
Begin
  UPDATE RESERVATIONS 
  SET Res_TotalAmount = 
    d.Res_TotalAmount * dbo.ufn_GetCancellationFactor(d.Res_StartDate)
  FROM RESERVATIONS r 
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON r.Reservation_ID = d.Reservation_ID
End 
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_GetCancellationFactor (@scheduledDate DATETIME) 
  RETURNS FLOAT AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @cancellationFactor FLOAT;
  DECLARE @period INT = DATEDIFF (DAY, @scheduledDate, GETDATE());

  SELECT @cancellationFactor = 
    CASE 
      WHEN @period <= 10 THEN 1.0             -- they owe the full amount (100%)
      WHEN @period BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 0.5 -- they owe 50%
      WHEN @period BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN 0.3 -- they owe 30% 
      ELSE 0                                  -- they owe nothing
    END

  RETURN @cancellationFactor;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Please rephrase your answer. There's not "previous" answer on SO. This is not a forum where answers are ordered by the date.

Comment: So rephrased! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thank you Robert. So I want to ask when I make delete of the reservation like 'delete from Reservation where reservation_ID = 86'how to be sure that SELECT @resID = Reservation_ID from deleted;" would give me this Reservation_ID which is 86 for example. Just I'm new to trigger and I can't find nothing on the matter

Answer (score 3):

Your fundamental flaw is that you seem to expect the trigger to be fired **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case in SQL Server. Instead, the trigger fires **once per statement**, and the pseudo table `Deleted` might contain **multiple rows**.

Given that that table might contain multiple rows - which one do you expect will be selected here??

```
Select @resID = Reservation_ID from deleted 
select @oldResAmount = Res_TotalAmount from deleted
Select @period= datediff (day,Res_StartDate,GETDATE()) from deleted
```

It's undefined - you might get the values from arbitrary rows in `Deleted`.

You need to rewrite your entire trigger with the knowledge the `Deleted` **WILL** contain multiple rows! You need to work with set-based operations - don't expect just a single row in `Deleted` !

Also: the `CASE` statement in T-SQL is just intended to return an atomic value - it's **not** a flow control statement like in other languages, and it cannot be used to execute code. So your `CASE` statement in your trigger is totally "lost" - it needs to be used in an assignment or something like that ....

Comment: marc_s I have made the trigger that way because my delete statement will try to delete really one row - 'delete from Reservarions where reservation_ID = 86' for example. you wrote 'It's undefined - you might get the values from arbitrary rows in Deleted.' Can you post code as I'm really new to tsql and triggers and time is pressuring me

Answer (score 0):

About the `case`:

The syntax is wrong. Even if it worked (see below) you'd be missing the `WHEN`s:

```
case 
    WHEN @period is between 30 and 20 then @newAmount=30%*@oldResAmount
    WHEN @period is between 20 and 10 then @newAmount=50%*@oldResAmount
end
```

Yet, the `case` statement can not be used this way. In the context where you want it, you need to use `if`. It's not like the `switch` statement in C++/C# for example. You can only use it in queries like

```
SELECT
case 
    WHEN @period is between 30 and 20 then value1
    WHEN @period is between 20 and 10 then value2
end
```

---

Having said the above: I didn't actually read all your code. But now that I've read some of it, it is really important to understand how triggers work in SQL Server, as `mark_s` says.